# How to set a variable equal to part of an input?

Tags: python, variables, declaration

Learning python and was interested in how to set a variable equal to part of an input.

For example

```
x = int(input("Input a 4 digit number"))
b = int(first 2 letters of x)
c = int(last 2 letters of x)
print b+c
```

ex. If they input 2051, it would print 71.

What notation would I need in b and c to complete this, or would I need something totally different?

Comment: Hint: use the plain arithmetic functions like `/` and `%` (divide and remainder).

Comment: You could convert it to a string to split them in two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could convert to `int` *after* splitting the string in half:

```
x = raw_input("Input a 4 digit number")
b, c = int(x[:2]), int(x[2:])
print b+c
```

I'm using slicing notation, which you can read more about [in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings). In a nutshell, the simplest form of the syntax is `string[start:end]`, where omitting `start` defaults to `0` (the beginning of the string) and omitting `end` will default to the end of the string. Therefore, `[2:]` will take the characters from index `2` to the end.

Note: From your `print` notation, it appears you're using Python 2. Therefore, I have changed the `input` to `raw_input`, since in Python 2, `input` automatically calls `eval` on the input, while `raw_input` will give you just the string.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to split string than to split an int, you can convert it after selecting the left,right 2 digits by casting to `in(x)`

```
x = input("Input a 4 digit number")
b = x[:2]
c = x[2:]
print int(b)+int(c)
```

If you wanna use numbers, you can use div, modulo to select first two, first last digits.

```
x = int(input("Input a 4 digit number"))
b = x%100
c = x//100
print b+c
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input is an integer, [divmod](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod) can be employed to serve your purpose

```
x = input("Input a 4 digit number")
b,c = divmod(x, 100)
print b + c
```

**Note** `divmod` would be preferred here because you do not need to swap between strings and numbers when this can effectively be handled mathematically . `divmod`, divided the number and returns the quotient and the remainder. This is the gist of what you are trying to achieve except that  you are summing them up.

You can even be a bit adventurous and can simply sum the quotient and remainder without an additional step

```
print sum(divmod(x, 100))
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep the user's input as a string, then verify it, then convert each part to an integer:

```
# Use a loop to re-prompt the user if their input is invalid
while True:
    user_input = raw_input("Input a 4 digit number: ")

    # Verify it is a number
    try:
        _ = int(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        print 'Invalid input given'
        continue

    # Verify it is 4 digits
    if len(user_input) != 4:
        print 'Input not 4 digits'
        continue

    # Parse the input into two separate values
    b = int(user_input[0:2])
    c = int(user_input[2:4])

    # Get out of this loop - the user has given valid input
    break

print 'First part:', b
print 'Second part:', c
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will split the string from the middle:

```
x = int(input("Input a 4 digit number"))
b = str(x)[:len(str(x)) / 2]
c = str(x)[len(str(x)) / 2:]
print b+c
```

Answer (score 0):

use slicing then `sum` function:

```
x = input("INput 4 digit number: ")
sum([int(x[:2]),int(x[2:])])
```

`sum` function will give you the sum of element of list

Answer (score 0):

you forgot bracets on line 4

```
x = raw_input("Input a 4 digit number")
```

b, c = int(x[:2]), int(x[2:])
print b+c